# Select results one by one in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I downloaded the source of one page from [Indeed](https://www.indeed.cl/trabajo?q=Data%20scientist&l=) and I'm trying to get all the job titles from there, for that I'm using this xpath:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="  row  result"]//*[@class="jobtitle"]//text()').extract()
```

The issue is that the results aren't in one line hence and getting this result:

```
[u'\n    ',
 u'Data',
 u' ',
 u'Scientist',
 u' Experto SQL con conocimiento en R',
 u'\n    ',
 u'\n    ',
 u'Data',
 u' Analytic con Python',
 u'\n    ',
 u'\n    ',
 u'Data',
 u' Analytic con R',
```

Which is problematic to map with the rest of the data, what I want is to select process the jobs one by one, something similar to extract_first()

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="  row  result"]').extract_first()
```

But for any given index and with the option to keep processing the data.
I tried this:

```
current_job = response.xpath('//*[@class="  row  result"]').extract_first()
current_job = TextResponse(url='',body=current_job,encoding='utf-8')
```

But it only works for the first result and it doesn't look like a pythonic approach to me.

Comment: Something like `if list_item.strip():`?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm looking for something built in on scrapy so I don't have to use TextResponse() each time, not sure if it exist.

Comment: can't you use `for` loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would get only `a` (without `text()` and `extract()`) and then I would use `for` to use `text()` and `extract()` with every `a` separatelly, and `join()` to concatenate elements to string with title.

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.cl/trabajo?q=Data%20scientist&l=']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        results = response.xpath('//h2[@class="jobtitle"]/a')
        print('number:', len(results))

        for item in results:
            title = ''.join(item.xpath('.//text()').extract())
            print('title:', title)

# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Result:

```
number: 10
title: Data Scientist
title: CONSULTOR DATA SCIENCE SANTIAGO DE CHILE
title: Líder Análisis de Datos MCoE Minerals Americas
title: Ingeniero Inteligencia Mercado, BI
title: Ingeniero Inteligencia de Mercado, Business Intelligence
title: Data Scientist
title: Data Scientist
title: Data Scientist (Machine Learning)
title: Data Scientist / Ml Scientist
title: Young Professional - Spanish LatAm
```

Comment: Thanks, one thing if the dot is not used in the second XPath the result is different, why is this?

Comment: with dot it is relative path and it search inside `<a>` which I have in `item` . Without dot it searchs in `<body>` so it can gets all text in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a go. You need to change my script a little to fit for your project. It can solve the issues you have mentioned above.

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

res = requests.get("https://www.indeed.cl/trabajo?q=Data%20scientist")
sel = Selector(res)
for item in sel.css("h2.jobtitle a"):
    title = ' '.join(item.css("::text").extract())
    print(title)
```

Output:

```
Data   Scientist
CONSULTOR  DATA  SCIENCE SANTIAGO DE CHILE
Líder Análisis de Datos MCoE Minerals Americas
Ingeniero Inteligencia Mercado, BI
Ingeniero Inteligencia de Mercado, Business Intelligence
Data   Scientist
Data   Scientist
Young Professional - Spanish LatAm
Data   Scientist  (Machine Learning)
Data   Scientist  / Ml  Scientist
```